# Trace tls in .NET Core

Tags: .net, .net-core

With .NET framework, we had this in the configuration so you could trace the `System.Net` and `System.Net.Sockets` namespaces, but how to do it in .NET Core? I've tried with no luck.

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true"/>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.Net" maxdatasize="1024">
      <listeners>
        <add name="TraceFile"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
    <source name="System.Net.Sockets" maxdatasize="1024">
      <listeners>
        <add name="TraceFile"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
  <sharedListeners>
    <add name="TraceFile" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
      initializeData="trace.log"/>
  </sharedListeners>
  <switches>
    <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose" />
    <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose" />
  </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: First why are you asking? If you have TLS issues post the error you get. Most likely it will explain what's wrong (eg expired or invalid certificate, no matching algorithms). A low-level trace won't help. Second, what you show logs all System.Net events, it's not specific to TLS troubleshooting and way too verbose. If you want to call an HTTPS service it's actually *easier* to use a debugging proxy like Fiddler to see what's going on, with TLS issues translated and shown explicitly

Comment: I need to see the end to end Cipher exchange for TLS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Low-level tracing of HTTP events isn't the best way to troubleshoot TLS issues because they're too low-level. I suspect the real problem is a mismatch in algorithms, otherwise the exception message would explain what's wrong, eg an untrusted or expired certificate.

An easier option is to use a debugging proxy like Fiddler which captures *and* translates the TLS handshake, showing what algorithms were requested.

As for tracing, it's evolved quite a bit since .NET Framework and since .NET 6 [Tracing can publish to various targets, including OpenTelemetry systems](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/performance-improvements-in-net-6/#tracing) as long as the correct sources are configured. As the linked article shows though, an easier but more expensive solution is to create an `EventListener` in the code which writes directly to console or ILogger, or anything else we want.

The blog example listens to `System.Net.Http` events. That's not enough to capture TLS algorithm negotiation though. This [Github Issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/64977) shows how to listen to the internal `Private.InternalDiagnostics.System.Net.Http` source. This results in a *lot* of very detailed messages, but they do include algorithms, thumbnails etc:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Diagnostics.Tracing;

internal sealed class HttpEventListener : EventListener
{
    protected override void OnEventSourceCreated(EventSource eventSource)
    {
        // Allow internal HTTP logging
        if (eventSource.Name == "Private.InternalDiagnostics.System.Net.Http")
        {
            EnableEvents(eventSource, EventLevel.LogAlways);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnEventWritten(EventWrittenEventArgs eventData)
    {
        // Log whatever other properties you want, this is just an example
        var sb = new StringBuilder().Append($"{eventData.TimeStamp:HH:mm:ss.fffffff}[{eventData.EventName}] ");
        for (int i = 0; i < eventData.Payload?.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0)
                sb.Append(", ");
            sb.Append(eventData.PayloadNames?[i]).Append(": ").Append(eventData.Payload[i]);
        }
        try {
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        } catch { }
    }
}
```

With that class you can start listening to low-level events :

```
var listener=new HttpEventListener();
var hc=new HttpClient();
await hc.GetStringAsync("https://dotnet.microsoft.com/");
```

This generates a *lot* of events, but one of them is this

```
08:34:11.4330369[HandlerMessage] poolId: 27011992, workerId: 6576978, requestId: 0, memberName: TraceConnection,     
message: HttpConnection(HttpConnectionPool https://dotnet.microsoft.com:443). SslProtocol:Tls12,                     
NegotiatedApplicationProtocol:, NegotiatedCipherSuite:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, CipherAlgorithm:Aes256, 
CipherStrength:256, HashAlgorithm:Sha384, HashStrength:0, KeyExchangeAlgorithm:44550, KeyExchangeStrength:256,       
LocalCertificate:, RemoteCertificate:[Subject]                                                                          CN=dotnet.microsoft.com, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=WA, C=US                                                                                                                                                                 ...
```

To listen to events from other libraries, modify the check in `OnEventSourceCreated`. You can find even the private event sources by checking the .NET repo directly. The event source for System.Net.Sockets is defined in [NetEventSource.Sockets.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Net.Sockets/src/System/Net/Sockets/NetEventSource.Sockets.cs#L11C49-L11C49) and its name is `Private.InternalDiagnostics.System.Net.Sockets`. That means `OnEventSourceCreated` can be changed to :

```
var monitoredSources=new[]{
    "Private.InternalDiagnostics.System.Net.Http",
    "Private.InternalDiagnostics.System.Net.Sockets"
};
if (monitoredSources.Contains(eventSource.Name))
{
    EnableEvents(eventSource, EventLevel.LogAlways);
}
```

Or even this, to record all System.Net diagnostic events

```
if (eventSource.Name.StartsWith("Private.InternalDiagnostics.System.Net"))
{
    EnableEvents(eventSource, EventLevel.LogAlways);
}
```

Comment: perfect! will this also work on System.Net.Sockets ?

Comment: You'll have to use a different Event source name, `Private.InternalDiagnostics.System.Net.Sockets`. The event sources are defined as classes in the various `System` libraries. `System.Net.Sockets` and `System.Net.Http` are different libraries. The Sockets event source is defined in [NetEventSource.Sockets.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Net.Sockets/src/System/Net/Sockets/NetEventSource.Sockets.cs#L11C49-L11C49)

Comment: works like a charm. Also adding Private.InternalDiagnostics.System.Net.Security will show the entire negotiation.